# Get parent class name?

Tags: python, oop

```
class A(object):
    def get_class(self):
        return self.__class__

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)

b = B()
print b.get_class()
```

This code will print `<class '__main__.B'>`.

How can I get the class name where the method has been defined (namely `A`)?

Comment: you better off to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961048/get-class-that-defined-method-in-python

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate... at least not of the one that it points to. Like not in any way. My solution to this question: self.__class__.__mro__[1].__name__

Answer (score 104, accepted):

From the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

Class objects have a `__name__` attribute.  It might cleaner to introspect the base class(es) through the `__bases__` attr of the derived class (if the code is to live in the derived class for example).

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     pass
...
>>> class Derived(Base):
...     def print_base(self):
...         for base in self.__class__.__bases__:
...             print base.__name__
...
>>> foo = Derived()
>>> foo.print_base()
Base
```

Comment: Will this work if you have a multi-inheritance scenario?

Answer (score 75):

> [`inspect.getmro(cls)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro)
>
> *Return a tuple of class cls’s base classes,
>   including cls, in method resolution order. No class appears more than
>   once in this tuple. Note that the method resolution order depends on
>   cls’s type. Unless a very peculiar user-defined metatype is in use,
>   cls will be the first element of the tuple.*

```
import inspect
inspect.getmro(B)
```

result will be:

```
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
```

First element is the class itself, second element is always first of the parents. After that things can get bit more complicated.

Comment: +1 for this, [`mro()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=mro#class.__mro__) is also useful

Comment: MRO is Method Resolution Order. check here e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848474/method-resolution-order-mro-in-new-style-classes

Answer (score -8):

You could change

```
return self.__class__

return A().__class__
```

Since there is no other instance of A() available...

Comment: Why not simply `return A`?