# Get base class' name?

Tags: python, class, oop

In Python I defined a class:

```
class Myclass(BaseModule):
```

I would like print argument `BaseModule`.

Something like this:

```
class Myclass(BaseModule):
     logger.info("Argument=%s" % BaseModule.get_name())
```

Doesn't work:

```
unbound method get_name() must be called with BaseModule instance as 
first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: BaseModule().get_name()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the error says, you need to instantiate (create an instance of) BaseModule first.

```
class MyClass(BaseModule):
    def __init__(self):
        base_mod = BaseModule()
        logger.info("Argument=%s", base_mod.get_name())
```

And it's not an argument, it's a parent class that `MyClass` inherits from. Argument is, for example, `self` from `__init__`. It's important to know the correct terminology to avoid confusion later.

Answer (score 7):

You can access the name of the class with:

```
BaseModule.__name__
```

Comment: +1 for helping show the OP the more Pythonic way of doing things, rather than just bashing in a solution for them. I was going to start suggesting a `@classmethod`, but a automagically defined variable is even better.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can find your answer here : 
[solution source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091957/how-to-get-parent-class-name-in-python)

```
    >>> class Base(object):
...     pass
...
>>> class Derived(Base):
...     def print_base(self):
...         for base in self.__class__.__bases__:
...             print base.__name__
...
>>> foo = Derived()
>>> foo.print_base()
Base
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a superclass method, you can use `super()`. But this will need you to have an instance, which you won't if you put your logging code there.

```
class Base(object):
    def get_name(self):
        return "Base name"

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print super(Derived, self).get_name()

Derived() # prints 'Base name'
```