# Django object - where does it inherit from?

Tags: python, oop

i' ve a Django model object. Is there any way to get to know (in code of course) where does it inherit from?

As an example:

```
class CDate(models.Models):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    active = models.BooleanField()

class SWT(CDate):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class RealObj(SWT):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

. In this case of a RealObj i' d like to get to know that it inhertis from SWT. How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all base classes in a hierarchy of given class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401661/list-all-base-classes-in-a-hierarchy-of-given-class)

Comment: Why would you need to know this? What's the actual use case?

Comment: The actual usecase is to move part of a django application from one server to another (i mean the database) and to get the overlapping IDs, but as there' re more than 100 objects, it' s good to know its type, so i can write some prechecks.

Comment: Thanks, inspect can be used for my goal. With inspect.getmro it' s pretty trivial to achieve my goal.

Comment: It looks like a similar answer exists here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091957/get-parent-class-name