# Determine class where method is defined in

Tags: python, inheritance

Given the following example, how can we determine at run-time that `A.__init__` belongs to class `A`?

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"We are in class {self.__class__}")
        # Prints "We are in class <class '__main__.B'>",
        # but desired result  is <class '__main__.A'>


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

B()
```

[Get class that defined method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961048/get-class-that-defined-method) is related, but not the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091957/get-parent-class-name. - Using the `inspect.getmro` I can see the classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import inspect

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        c = inspect.getmro(self.__class__)
        print(f"We are in class {c}")
        # Prints "We are in class <class '__main__.B'>",
        # but desired result  is <class '__main__.A'>


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

B()
A()
```

Output:

```
We are in class (<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
We are in class (<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```