# Get class that defined method inside the method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datamodel

How can I get the class that defined a method in Python?

For example

```
class A(object):
    def meth(self):
        return **get_current_class()**
class B(A):
    def meth(self):
        do_something
        return super(B,self).meth()

>>> b=B()
>>> b.meth() ##that return the class A
```

Since b.__class__ is always the actual class of b(that is B),and what I want is the class which actual defined the method(that should be A),so self.__class__ is useless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get class that defined method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961048/get-class-that-defined-method)

Answer (score 1):

To return the class that defined the method, the simplest way would be to just do it directly:

```
class A(object):
    def meth(self):
        return A
```

---

If `meth` is defined outside the class -- and presumably attached to more than one class -- it may not be feasible to hardcode the class in the body of `meth`. In that case, perhaps the easiest (only?) way for `meth` to know the class on which it is defined is to store that information in `meth` (as an attribute) at the time it is attached to the class.

Instead of attaching the function `meth` to the class `A` with

```
A.meth = meth
```

I propose using a function `setmeth` which performs both `A.meth = meth` *and* `meth.thisclass = A`:

```
def setmeth(cls, name, meth):
    setattr(cls, name, meth)
    setattr(meth, 'thisclass', cls)

def meth(self):
    print(meth.thisclass)

class A(object): pass
setmeth(A, 'meth', meth)

class B(A):
    def meth(self):
        return super(B, self).meth()

b=B()
b.meth() ##that return the class A
```

prints

```
<class '__main__.A'>
```

Comment: in my case,I can't simply type this class name because I'm implementing a function which need to use the class of the method who invoke it and I don't want to put this class in the argument everytime.

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't quite follow you. Do you mean the function is defined outside of the class? Could you post some more code to make the situation clearer?

Comment: @ubuntu yes,this function (get_current_class) is defined outside an it could return A inside A.meth.

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3130/  ,in the pep 3130 ,\__class__ is exactly what I want,Unfortunately it has been rejected

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an odd thing to want to do, and you can't do it without getting extremely hacky. One possible solution is to realize that a method is a member of `__dict__` on the class that defines it, so you can ascend the MRO to find the first one that has the method name in that dict:

```
def get_class_for_method(self, method_name):
    for cls in self.__class__.mro():
        if method_name in cls.__dict__:
            return cls
```

Comment: In yjmade's case, `self.__class__.mro()` includes `B` before `A`, so `B.meth` will be found before `A.meth`. Unfortunately, I don't think this is going to work...

Comment: yes,@ubuntu is right,I need to know which class's method invoke the get_current_class function