# How to get class name when there is attribute attached?

Tags: python, class, methods

For example,

I want to return 'ClassName' from the following:

```
ClassName().MethodName
```

When I try:

```
ClassName().MethodName.__class__.__name__

>>instancemethod
```

or when I try:

```
ClassName().MethodName.__name__

>>MethodName
```

Perhaps this isn't possible, so would there be a way to turn ClassName().MethodName to ClassName(), so I could then run this, which is what I want:

```
ClassName().__class__.__name__
>> ClassName
```

Comment: `repr(method_name).rpartition('.')[-1].split()[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
class Foo(object):
    def MethodName():
        pass

print type(Foo()).__name__ 
# Foo
```

Or,

```
foo=Foo()
print type(foo).__name__
# Foo
```

(Note -- that only works on new style classes, not legacy classes. It obviously only works if you know what to call to instantiate the class)

If all you have is reference to a method, you can use inspect ([Thx Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/961057/298607)):

```
import inspect

def get_class_from_method(meth):
  for cls in inspect.getmro(meth.im_class):
    if meth.__name__ in cls.__dict__: return cls
  return None

>>> mn=Foo().MethodName
>>> get_class_from_method(mn).__name__
Foo
```

Or, for a [user defined method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), you can do:

```
>>> mn.im_class.__name__
Foo
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer OP's question, which is given a *method*, how to get the class's name

Comment: I still receive instancemethod

Comment: Try now (with the last two methods.) Is this a new or old style class?

Answer (score 3):

The information you want is in the `im_class` attribute of the bound method object:

```
>>> class Foo():
...   def bar():
...     pass
...
>>> m = Foo().bar
>>> m.im_class
<class __main__.Foo at 0x1073bda78>
```