# python: Invoke super class method in a function decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

Mostly well-known, here's how to call a super class's overloaded method `f`.

```py
class Base:
    def f(self, *args):
        print(f"BASE method invoked.")

class Inherit(Base):
    def f(self, *args):
        super(Inherit, self).f(*args) # Calling overloaded method
```

However, if I don't know `f`, and instead, it's passed as an argument `func`, how shall I rewrite the `super...` statement? An example context is to define a decorator that applies some uniform operation to all the overloaded functions.

### Clarification and more details:

In the following example, I have a `Base` class that is a library not owned by me. It has severals (20+) methods `f`, `g` etc that internally makes some remote procedure calls (RPC). The library documentation suggests subclassing the `Base` to use it.

For debugging purpose, I would like to record a log every time a RPC is called. So I'd like to make a uniform function decorator `log_rpc` for all the RPC methods.

```py
def log_rpc(func):
    """This does not work"""
    def new_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Invoking RPC {METHODNAME} with parameters: {locals()}")
        super(CLASSNAME, self).METHODNAME(*args, **kwargs) # Two issues here.
    return new_func

class Base: # This is provided by some library
    def f(self, *args):
        # rpc_client.f() # make some rpc calls.
        print(f"BASE method invoked.")

    def g(self, *args):
        # rpc_client.g() # make some rpc calls.
        print(f"BASE method invoked.")

class Inherit(Base): # My own code subclassing the library
    @log_rpc
    def f(self, *args):
        """function body will be ignored by the decorator."""
        pass

    @log_rpc
    def g(self, *args):
        """function body will be ignored by the decorator."""
        pass

Inherit().f()
```

However, when making a generic decorator independent of `Inherit` class or method `f`, there are two emerging issues

1. How do I figure out the `CLASSNAME` in the decorator? Since the decorator is invoked during the class `Inherit` is being constructed, I can't use module's `__qualname__` to retrieve the `Inherit` class object.
2. How do I figure out the `METHODNAME` in the decorator?

What I have searched so far:

- A similar question [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921537/how-do-i-call-super-in-a-method-decorator-in-python-3) but does not have a solution.
- Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=data%20model#invoking-descriptors) about `super` and descriptor mechanism.

Comment: Are you aware that you could get the same effect as your `call_base` by just not overriding the method at all?

Comment: Yes. The example is for simplicity only. I can certainly add more logic around invoking the base methods.

Comment: Could you provide some actual context of the problem you're trying to solve? It's not clear to me why you'd want to do this.

Comment: Some more realistic context: Let's say we'd like to record each time an overloaded function is invoked. I can add a `print(f"overloaded method {METHODNAME} invoked")` in the decorator. The benefit of this is I only need to write once in the decorator, instead of 100 times in each overloaded function.

Comment: You might also reconsider this design: https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CallSuper.html