# Python: How to determine attribute MRO

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

We can easily determine an object's mro, by accessing its `__mro__` attribute.

In my case I have a really complex hierarchy that I'm trying to untangle to avoid the current mro hell we are undergoing.

I have a very long mro chain like this one:

```
(<class 'CompanyUserViewSet'>, <class 'CompanyGenericViewSet'>, 
 <class 'CompanyDispatchMixin'>, <class 'CompanyCorsLiteMixin'>, 
 <class 'CorsLiteMixin'>, <class 'ErrorHandlingMixin'>, ..., <type 'object'>)
```

This is shortened for the sake of the question, but in this case it sums up to `19` classes.

I currently have a problem: I need to know from which one of these classes python is resolving the `as_view` method.

I know I can check these in order, but I fail to see what I'm doing wrong, since the `as_view` that is getting called is not the correct one.

The call to the method is pretty simple, we have a `CompanyUserViewSet` that Rest Framework is using to build the urls for a router:

```
view = viewset.as_view(mapping, **route.initkwargs)
```

How can I determine, given an object and one of its attributes (or methods) from what class is python resolving it?

Comment: how is it being called?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham on an instance of the first type in the list

Comment: Are their metaclasses involved? Are parent implementations called via `super`? There are a few variables that can change the default MRO.

Comment: I was probably unclear, I mean are you using super() in a class or Class.method or simply inheriting?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham well, no metaclass issues for sure, but there are 19 classes, some used super, others didn't. `qualname` solved the issue in a second :)

Comment: You can do it without any package http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961048/get-class-that-defined-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get where a method is defined use, `method.__func__.__qualname__`. That requires Python >= 3.3. In older pythons you can use the [qualname](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qualname/) package.

See the example below:

```
class A:
  def f1():
    return 'f1A'
  def f2():
    return 'f2A'

class B(A):
  def f2():
    return 'f2B'

a = A()
b = B()
print(a.f1.__func__.__qualname__)
print(a.f2.__func__.__qualname__)
print(b.f1.__func__.__qualname__)
print(b.f2.__func__.__qualname__)
```

which produces the output:

```
A.f1
A.f2
A.f1
B.f2
```

If you are using the qualname package:

```
import qualname
print qualname.qualname(a.f1)
print qualname.qualname(a.f2)
print qualname.qualname(b.f1)
print qualname.qualname(b.f2)
```

Comment: This. This worked like a charm, don't get the downvote