# Determine the defining class from within a method

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.5

The following Python 3.5 code:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("My type is", type(self))

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("My type is", type(self))

d = Derived()
```

prints:

```
My type is <class '__main__.Derived'>
My type is <class '__main__.Derived'>
```

I would like to know, inside each `__init__()`, the class where the method was defined, not the deriving class. So I would get the following print:

```
My type is <class '__main__.Base'>
My type is <class '__main__.Derived'>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961048/get-class-that-defined-method.

Comment: @alecxe I saw that link, it's not relevant to my question since 1) both Base and Derived have __init__ method so relaying on the name is not helpful. 2) I would like to know the defining class from within the __init__ method, and for any level of inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

Use `super().__thisclass__`:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("My type is", super().__thisclass__)

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("My type is", super().__thisclass__)

d = Derived()

My type is <class '__main__.Base'>
My type is <class '__main__.Derived'>
```

## Solution 2

Not as elegant but hard-wiring the class works:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("My type is", Base)

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("My type is", Derived)

d = Derived()
```

Output:

```
My type is <class '__main__.Base'>
My type is <class '__main__.Derived'>
```

Comment: Indeed super().__thisclass__ (solution 1) does the trick.This is exactly what I needed.