# python decorator that calls super init

Tags: python, reflection, decorator

I'm trying to make a decorator that automatically calls the parent class init. It works with single inheritance but when I try to chain the effect I get a stack overflow error. Can anyone explain (a) Why this is happening and (b) How to accomplish what I want to accomplish?

```
def init(__init):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__class__.__bases__[0].__init__(self)
        __init(self)
    return wrapper

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print("base init")


class Parent(Base):
    @init
    def __init__(self):
        print("parent init")

class Child(Parent):
    @init
    def __init__(self):
        print("child init")

a = Parent() #works
#c = Child() #stack overflow
```

Comment: Take a look at what `self.__class__` is in the second case. It will always be `Parent` because `self` never stops being an instance of `Child`, no matter what method you call on it.

Comment: You want to have a reference to the class that contains the `__init` that you are calling. That will ensure that your recursion eventually terminates.

Comment: what is the point of this decorator actually???

Comment: Don't bother trying to make this decorator work. It's going to be a difficult journey full of traps. Just call the parent `__init__` in your constructor like everyone else. It's only a few characters longer than typing `@init` anyway.

Comment: @Rawing. I hope I've captured your sentiment in my answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I thought I could condense some of my boilerplate down to a single decorator. I was aware that when I'm starting to write things like "self.__class__.__bases__[0]" I'm probably off in the weeds but I was curious and wanted to learn what was going on

Comment: @JohnK. Picking which method to call is not really boilerplate. If you have multiple parent classes, you have to make the decision as to which `__init__`s to call very carefully on a case-by-case basis. Using a decorator like that will not work at all.

Answer (score 4):

**The Right Way**

The correct way to do this would be to call the parent initializer in your code directly. In Python 3:

```
super().__init__()
```

In Python 2:

```
super(Parent, self).__init__()
```

or

```
super(Child, self).__init__()
```

**The Error**

To answer your immediate question though, the infinite recursion happens because of how you get the parent:

```
self.__class__.__bases__[0]
```

`self` will not stop being an instance of `Child` no matter how many times you call your `wrapper` function. You end up calling `Parent.__init__(self)` indefinitely because the parent class never changes.

**The Wrong Way**

What you probably want is to find the class that defined the `__init__` method you are currently calling, and get the parent of that. @AlexMartelli has provided a function that does this or Python to in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/961057/2988730), which I am copying verbatim here:

```
import inspect

def get_class_that_defined_method(meth):
    for cls in inspect.getmro(meth.im_class):
        if meth.__name__ in cls.__dict__: 
            return cls
    return None
```

I you are using Python 3, use [@Yoel's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25959545/2988730) instead:

```
def get_class_that_defined_method(meth):
    if inspect.ismethod(meth):
        for cls in inspect.getmro(meth.__self__.__class__):
           if cls.__dict__.get(meth.__name__) is meth:
                return cls
        meth = meth.__func__  # fallback to __qualname__ parsing
    if inspect.isfunction(meth):
        cls = getattr(inspect.getmodule(meth),
                      meth.__qualname__.split('.<locals>', 1)[0].rsplit('.', 1)[0])
        if isinstance(cls, type):
            return cls
    return getattr(meth, '__objclass__', None)  # handle special descriptor objects
```

You can now redefine your `init` function as follows:

```
def init(__init):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        get_class_that_defined_method(__init).__bases__[0].__init__(self)
        __init(self)
    return wrapper
```

Again. Please do not do this. There are probably many corner cases that I have not covered that will come and bite you, starting with everything around `__bases__[0]`. Just use `super` instead. It is a much better thought out version of the same idea anyway.