# Is it possible to access the class object from any of its defined method?

Tags: python, class

Supposed I am given a variable pointing to a method of a class, is it possible to retrieve the variable pointing to its class?

For example, I have the following class,

```py
class AClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        return None

    def instance_method(self):
        return None

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        return None
```

say, I am given only `AClass.instance_method` variable, is it possible to get `Aclass` based on that?

such that I could define a function with the following outcome.

```py
def get_its_class(AClass.method):
   ....

   return AClass
```

And I hope such a function can work for class methods, static methods, and (instance) methods?

Comment: does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961048/get-class-that-defined-method

Comment: @go2nirvana unfortunately no, im_class is no longer an attribute of a method in python 3. Also as I read the other comments of that post, it seems there might be some other implementations for python 3, which I will further check.