# Check if a function is defined within a Python class

Tags: python, function, class, methods, inspect

What is the correct way in Python 3.7+ to check if a function is defined within a Python class. Example:

```
class A:

    def fun1(self):
        pass

def fun2():
    pass
```

I would like to distinguish that `A.fun1` was defined within a class and `fun2` is not.

Comment: You're asking `magic(A.fun1)` should return `True` and `magic(fun2)` should return `False`, right?

Comment: what is the point of doing this? what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: There are [inspect.ismethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod) and [inspect.isfunction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction). `ismethod` should be called on object. Do these: `print(inspect.ismethod(A().fun1), inspect.isfunction(A().fun1)); print(inspect.ismethod(fun2), inspect.isfunction(fun2))`.

Comment: @deceze Exactly

Comment: @Arty  As you pointed out, is method requires instantiating the class which might not be possible or easy or have side effects in certain cases.

Comment: @marcusshep I want to modify a callable differently when acting on static methods, class methods, methods or functions. Right now I have four distinct decorators, but it would be easier from the user perspective to have a single decorator that dispatch to the right implementation based on the target. When I tried to implement this, I was not able to find a robust way to get this information for an uninstatiated class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the attribute [`__qualname__`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name) (defined in [PEP 3155](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/)) and check whether it contains a `.` which indicates that this object was defined in a nested scope. Note that this also applies to functions defined inside other functions, so it might give you false positives in that sense.

```
>>> def test(): ...
... 
>>> test.__qualname__
'test'
>>> class Foo:
...     def test(self): ...
... 
>>> Foo.test.__qualname__
'Foo.test'
>>> def f():
...     def g(): ...
...     return g
... 
>>> f().__qualname__
'f.<locals>.g'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go [hasattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr)

```
>>> hasattr(A, 'fun1')
>>> True

>>> hasattr(A, 'fun2')
>>> False
```

Comment: And how is my answer not solving that problem?

Comment: Method is a function defined within a class. Determining if class has a specific function is exactly equal to "distinguish that function was defined within a class" - as OP requested.

Comment: Well, i answer what was asked in the question, not playing a "guess what that really means" game.

Comment: In this particular case question was very clear for me, so i see no need to clarify. In fact, if you take a look at answer's at deceze's suggestion: the third answer (and 2nd most voted) is the same as mine. This concludes to me, that questions in fact are similar. And rather than doubting my answer, the appropriate action would be to flag question as duplicate. Anyway, i suggest we move on.

Comment: @go2nirvana I thought that the last phrase in my question was clarifying this: "I would like to distinguish that A.fun1 was defined within a class and fun2 is not"  Which is not the same as saying if a given class defines a function with a given name.

Comment: @Hernan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961048/get-class-that-defined-method