# Python: dynamically asserting the class name of a function to insert into its docstring when calling the help function on it

Tags: python, functools

I have a setup that looks as following:

```
def docstring_formatter(func):
    func.__doc__ = func.__doc__.format(class_name=func.__self__.__class__.__name__) #this does not work
    return func

class A:
    @docstring_formatter
    def my_function(self):
        """I am a function of class {class_name}"""
        print("test")

class B(A):
    pass

docstring = getattr(B.my_function, "__doc__")
>>> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__self__'
```

I would like to access the actual class name that the instance of my_function belongs to. Since I am not instantiating the class I when I am using the `help()` function, the `__self__` property is not instantiated yet and I can also not make use of the `functools.wraps` function. I would like to find a way to also extract the string `B` or `B.my_function` when being passed a `my_function` object that could either belong to `A()` or `B()`.

Comment: I think this post would be of great help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961048/get-class-that-defined-method

Answer (score 2):

Given the code:

```
class A:
    def my_function(self):
        print("test")

class B(A):
    pass

b = B()
```

The `my_function` object has a `self` binding to the object you took it from, which is a `B`, so you can do:

```
>>> b.my_function.__name__
'my_function'
>>> b.my_function.__self__.__class__.__name__
'B'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately my current setup differs a bit from what I posted, since I am not calling the function directly but rather calling the `help()` function on it to access its docstring, which means that the class is not properly instantiated yet and I can't make the reference to `__self__` on my function. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Your updated example doesn't work because the argument to `docstring_formatter` is `A.my_function`, not `b.my_function` as in your original question.  There is no `B`, and there isn't even an instance of `A`, until after `docstring_formatter` has already returned.  I'd suggest writing your own `help` function so that it can inspect `b.my_function` before doing its formatting on `b.my_function.__doc__`.

Comment: I messed around a bit with trying to do this in `__init__` since that does have access to the instance that the method is bound to, but it turns out you can't modify the `__doc__` attribute of a bound method.  So yeah, you want to put this logic in `help`, which means you need to override the builtin version.